Add label to right y axis in R plotly
I previously had this question answered and it worked perfectly using ggplot.
Now, I want the same using plotly. I'd like the "Goal" to be labeled on the right side. Is it as easy as it is in ggplot? Thanks!
Here's the code for ease:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  group_val = c(rep('Class A', 10), rep('Class B', 10)),
  x_val = c(seq(1,10), seq(1,10)),
  y_val = c(3,5,4,6,8,11,10,9,8,12,
            6,2,3,6,8,10,12,14,16,8)
)

goal <- 16


df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x_val, y=y_val, group=group_val, color=group_val)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = goal,
             linetype="dashed")


You will find that this question already exists. See if this Q&A helps.
